# 5 to 10 GB of text files to download?

Tags: file, text, dataset

I am trying to find plain english text files (txt) in the range of 5 to 10 GB to perform an indexing and searching task. Are there any open sources where I can download such a dataset?

Thanks

Wajih

Comment: a massive hashtable, is that what your looking for?

Comment: @PatrickLorio - I am looking for plain text. Not a massive hashtable. Something that I can simply read off the disk as pure text and not do any parsing. I mean MS-Word files and sorts is NOT what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kinda needed the same thing when doing research for my masters a couple years ago. What I did is combine multiple books from this site:

http://www.gutenberg.org/

Comment: It depends on the book's length, I remember using a lot of books with the title encyclopedia, and on average each of them were about 10 MB plain text files. I know it's not the whole dataset you're looking for, but you could join them and come up with the desired size.

Comment: The great thing is that because those are english books, and not just a collection of random words, it's the perfect dataset to try on search algorithm in real situations, at least that's why I did.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using BitTorrent to download a [DVD of Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:The_CD_and_DVD_Project). They have several GB of public domain texts in mostly ASCII format.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this freebase.com data dump on Amazon S3 http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/2320?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1